# how to close bottom modal sheet in mobile view using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, android-intent, upi

once click on the upi apps link `upi://=7838304007@cosb&pn=QWRhbSBJbm5vdmF0aW9ucyBUZXN0&tr=ID17746409&tn=Pay` this will open android bottom sheet list the all upi apps. i need to fail the txn after some time, and redirecting to new page using trigger click event. redirection is working fine, byt the bottom modal sheet is not closing. is there any way to close?[image: screenshot for the issue]